# Why can we use `this` inside AXIOS arrow handlers in VueJS?

Tags: javascript

I am coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63210362/vuejs-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-settings-of-undefined) where I couldn't use `this` inside the following method:

```
methods: {
    changeUrl: _.debounce((e) => {
      this.settings.url = e.target.value;
    }, 500),
  },
```

This threw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined`.
The answer was that we can't use `this` inside arrow functions:

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target` keywords.

But then I've noticed that I was using arrow functions inside axios handlers:

```
    sendData() {
      server
        .post("/endpoint", data)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status == 200) {
            this.message = "Data was sent";
          } else {
            this.message = "Something went wrong. Please try again";
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.message = "";
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

And the above code isn't throwing any error and is working perfectly.

**Why isn't `this.message` throwing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`**

What's more, if I change the above code to use normal functions instead of arrow functions:

```
    sendData() {
      server
        .post("/endpoint", data)
        .then(function(res) {
          if (res.status == 200) {
            this.message = "Data was sent";
          } else {
            this.message = "Something went wrong. Please try again";
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          this.message = "";
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

this will throw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`.

**Why ?**

Comment: Because you're calling this within your object instance which has a `.message` property. Arrow functions use the lexical `this` from their definition location, hence why that works for you. Normal functions will use the `this`  they are invoked with, which is *not* going to be the same as the context where they are defined.

Comment: Also relevant: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484) | [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm glad you linked that as dupe. I was hesitating whether to go with that question or the equivalent / exchangeable one. Ideally both are relevant.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, I wish mere mortals could flag multiple duplicate targets.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'd love it if silver badge holders were given a bit more leeway like suggesting multiple dupes. Seems like a natural extension to then link multiple dupes explicitly with a gold badge.

Comment: one only needs mention to plob bind on the end of the function `function() { }.bind(this)`, OP wont see the dupes for the trees